# Benchmarking crono scheduler in enterprise level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.3

I have been using [Crono gem](https://github.com/plashchynski/crono) in some personal applications. Now I was planning to use Crono in my current organization, to schedule jobs at enterprise level.

I wanted to know if any one have already run some benchmarking tests for the performance/load/jobs that Crono can handle. If not, any suggestions how to do such an evaluation?